# Custom Menu Anchor Links Not Working

Tags: menus

I've got anchor links in the nav menu of my site, and I can't get them to work properly. The site keeps prepending the siteurl before the anchor link. With the #rsvp anchor link, I've tried using the whole URL (communityengagement.nyc/#rsvp), putting it in single quotes ('#rsvp'), prepending a slash (/#rsvp) and still can't get it to work.

I dug into the php a bit to see if I could figure it out but I haven't had any luck.

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 1):

First: congrats!

The links are well formed, so that is not your problem.

```
<a id="rsvp" rel="m_PageScroll2id"></a>
```

Is not the convention in HTML5 anymore. You should prefer to put the ID in your H2 element. Something like this:

```
<h2 class="entry-title" id="rsvp">RSVP</h2>
```

Using Google Chrome, when I tried that, I still got the same problem: your entire page goes blank on my client when I click on the link. Your error is not with the link structure. I strongly suspect that the theme has an error in the styles or the java script that accidentally causes all text and images to disappear.

But, at least you know that your links are fine.

Comment: Phew! That makes me feel better. Ok! Back to the theme folks for support. And thanks for the congrats!